# How to make auto completion in WebStorm (*.js) and IntelliJ (*.go) work the same

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, webstorm

In WebStorm I can type something like

```
document.gEBI
```

press tab key, and it'll autocomplete to

```
document.getElementById()
```

But when I do the similar thing in IntelliJ

```
fmt.Prl
```

Auto completion doesn't work (the desired result `fmt.Println()`) at all, it works only if all the letters match strictly in order.

Is it possible to enable this functionality in IntelliJ? I've imported all the settings from WebStorm.

Comment: The autocomplete should work the same -- it's an IDE-wide/platform feature, especially in this aspect (although there is always a chance that some details are language-specific). I'm not a Go user myself .. so: 1) Show you code completion settings 2) show how code completion popup looks when you type your `fmt.Prl`

Answer (score 0):

These <kbd>Tab</kbd> key shortcuts aren't part of the auto-complete system the Jetbrains use for all their IDEs as LazyOne says, they are actually part of the template-invocation system.

The auto-complete functionality is built into the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

I suggest looking up the template invocation for `.Println()` in the settings, Jetbrains documentation, or raising a ticket with Jetbrains on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) for clearer documenation/control over template-invocation.